# Question of an example from lshort

Tags: pdftex

Here is an example of how to use `\settowidth` to obtain dynamic width in the book *lshort*.

```
\flushleft
\newenvironment{vardesc}[1]{%
\settowidth{\parindent}{#1:\ }
\makebox[0pt][r]{#1:\ }}{}
\begin{displaymath}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{displaymath}
\begin{vardesc}{Where}$a$,
$b$ -- are adjacent to the right
angle of a right-angled triangle.
$c$ -- is the hypotenuse of
the triangle and feels lonely.
$d$ -- finally does not show up
here at all. Isn’t that puzzling?
\end{vardesc}
```

[image]

It's a very interesting example. But when I type it in the `C` language style

```
\newenvironment{vardesc}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\parindent}{#1:\ }
    \makebox[0pt][r]{#1:\ }
}{}
```

the output is different.
[image]

The same happened when I use the defined `vardesc` environment:

```
\begin{vardesc}{Where}
$a$,$b$ -- are adjacent to the right angle of a right-angled triangle.

$c$ -- is the hypotenuse of the triangle and feels lonely.

$d$ -- finally does not show up here at all. Isn't that puzzling?
\end{vardesc}
```

[image]

The author write `$a$` right after `{Where}` deliberately. I have no idea why this could happened. I mean I must write the code by myself but not just copy it from the book. So what's the good habit to do things like this right.

Comment: There seems to be a missing `%`…

Comment: You put `}{}` on a new line, one line earlier, put a `%` sign at the end (just as is done in the first line). Same later `{Where}%` (although one could come up with a better thing here).

Comment: Really this environment does not look like production-ready code. One example is putting the a on the same line, the other example is using this environment with different line breaks and the slight shift of "a" in the output. But of course it shows how to use `\settowidth`.

Comment: what's the function of the `%` sign(when not regard as a commment sign)?

Comment: It ignores spaces, e.g. one line break.

Comment: it _is_ being used as a comment in all your fragments

Comment: The command `\flushleft` should not be used in the wild. In this case, if you *really* need it, it should be `\begin{flushleft}` at the start with a matching `\end{flushleft}` later. That `\flushleft` is scattered everywhere in `lshort` and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear to me whether you want the  word ‘Where’ in the margin or not. So here are two simple solutions based on `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{vardesc}[1]{%
\enumerate[wide=0pt, widest={#1:}, leftmargin=*]
\item[#1:]}
{\endenumerate}%

\newenvironment{varDesc}[1]{%
\itemize[leftmargin=0pt ]
\item[#1:]}%
{\enditemize}%
    \begin{document}

\flushleft
\begin{displaymath}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{displaymath}
\begin{vardesc}{Where}
$a$,$b$ -- are adjacent to the right angle of a right-angled triangle.

$c$ -- is the hypotenuse of the triangle and feels lonely.

$d$ -- finally does not show up here at all. Isn't that puzzling?
\end{vardesc}%

\begin{varDesc}{Where}
$a$,$b$ -- are adjacent to the right angle of a right-angled triangle.

$c$ -- is the hypotenuse of the triangle and feels lonely.

$d$ -- finally does not show up here at all. Isn't that puzzling?
\end{varDesc}%at all. Isn't that puzzling?

\end{document}
```

[image]